# Json evaluation - trouble with accents

Tags: c#, json.net

[image]Huy guys!

I'm having some trouble with accents when I directly make a query on facebook website.

When content have accents, the website returns something like this:

"__html":"M\u00fasico/Banda"

But testing with JsonParserOnline (http://json.parser.online.fr/) they divide 2 columns, and the last one is "JSEval", where they can normalize the Json, like this:

"__html":"Músico/Banda"

How can i normalize this since i already have the string?

I attached a sample with my query to be more specific.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"__html":"M\u00fasico/Banda"` is a correct JSON encoding for the string.  `\u00fa` is specifying a UNICODE code point.  Any JSON parser in c# will handle this.

Comment: But actualy when i deserialize, json.net doesn´t handle the json string. This is how I do: People people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<People> (json);

Comment: @BrenoRiba How are you doing the deserialisation, and how are you testing that?

Comment: Sorry Richard, actualy json.net can handle this. I was confused about this return. Thank you guys! I appreciate your help =D

Comment: It's not "the correct" as this - incorrectly - implies the alternative is incorrect. JSON strings are Unicode so it is merely an *alternative* encoding of a JSON string value (which is perhaps required in a JSON application that only emits ASCII).

Comment: @pst, I see your point. I perhaps should have said `is **a** correct JSON encoding`.